# How do I repair a crashing pinyin on linux?

Tags: linux, input-languages

For seemingly no reason whatsoever, my ibus-libpinyin has started crashing again. I'm slowly getting paranoid and worry that someone might be trying to prevent me from learning Chinese, but that's probably a ridiculous conspiracy theory; however, apparently the crashes have appeared for no specific reason.

What happens is this: Every now and again, the software will type Roman characters instead of Chinese ones, even though the Chinese mode is active. Then, sometimes I can't type anything; the selection box will just disappear without any characters being typed when I press the space bar.

Does anyone know what might be going on here? Since I'm very fond of foreign languages, I'd be pleased if there was a fix.

Thank you very much in advance!